# Kafka is throwing an Exception while starting

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka is throwing an exception while starting,

Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
Followed by null pointer exception.

I have increased the config/server.properties connection time out but still has the issue.
Here am using the windows Os.

Thanks

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:230)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:95)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1580)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.kafka$server$KafkaServer$$createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:348)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:372)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2018-09-04 23:31:35,864] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: You need to post the errors and relevant configuration too.

Comment: Hey Giorgos, posted the log

Comment: Is zookeeper running?

Comment: You also need to post kafka configuration too (`server.properties` file).

Comment: Also, in your question you mentioned a `NullPointerException` but I cannot find it in the logs you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting the system it got started working.it did not work even  changing the kafka server.properties, but its working now as my machine got started.

Thanks every one for helping me to debug.